# Flutter change validation error message position

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have Flutter app which consist of TextFormField (email) is there is a way after validation to change the position of the error message of this validation it appears under the TextFormField , So I want it appear in the TextFormfield itself

Answer (score 2):

The `TextFormField` widget follows the MaterialDesign guidelines. So you can't easily customise it like you want.

To put your error message on top of your textfield, you can use a `Stack` widget.
You will have to show/hide your error playing with the focus of your Textfield.

Comment: So I return validation string error into null in this case ?